# How do I set the last line of the prompt to only print user input?

Tags: ruby

My application has two threads: one processes the info, the other gathers user input. Eventually, the first one logs some info on the command line, and the problem is that if I'm typing while information is logged, the info is printed in front of my text, and it is very confusing and annoying. I would like to know the best way to have a line only for user input, so that all the output get printed above this line. I've searched a lot, and there doesn't seem to be a gem that specifically does that.

Comment: As it is logging info, is there a reason it is not being directed to a log file?

Comment: Actually it is, but I like reading the log directly from the console. I know it's very stupid, I could just trace the log file, but I just want to have a complete console.

Comment: In that case, I am confused at how you think it would end up anywhere else on the standard out?  I guess you could use some sort of vertical manipulation of the output.  Or perhaps, simply open a second screen??